# how to allow clients connecting to some websites over proxy with their IPs?

Tags: proxy, iptables, squid, http-proxy

I am config squid as forward proxy and everything work correctly.
Some websites block my squid server IP and when a client trying connect to that websites over my proxy sever,it can not access to them.
I want to telling squid that when a client request that website, squid lets clients to connect to that website directly and do not using proxy server public IP address for this connection and using clients real IP instead of server IP.

Answer (score 0):

Set x-forwarded-for option in your squid config for all domains